# How to show that $E[X_n]$ converges to $E[X]$ when $X_n$ converges in $L_1$?

Tags: statistics, convergence-divergence, random-variables, expected-value

The question that I encounter is:

Suppose $X_n \overset{L_1}{\longrightarrow} X$, then show that $\mathbb{E}[X_n]\rightarrow \mathbb{E}[X]$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

My thoughts on this: I can show that $\mathbb{E}[|X_n|] \rightarrow \mathbb{E}[|X|]$ by the triangular inequality with respect to the $L_1$ norm but I'm stuck on how to proceed from here. I think it's not generally true that convergence in the expectation of the absolute value implies convergence in the expectation of the random variable itself.

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|EX_n-EX|=|E(X_n-X)| \leq E|X_n-X| \to 0$ so $EX_n \to EX$.

Proof of the inequality $|EY| \leq E|Y|$: We have $Y \leq |Y|$ so $EY \leq E|Y|$. Similarly, $-Y \leq |Y|$ gives $-EY=E(-Y) \leq E|Y|$. Since $|EY|$ is one of the number $EY, -EY$ it folllows that $|EY| \leq E|Y|$.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! Do you have a name for the inequality that you are using in the equation above?

Comment: @JamieCarr I have included a proof.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Sorry to ask you again but do you think the converse of this statement is true? i.e., does convergence in mean implies convergence in $L_1$?

Comment: @JamieCarr Think how easy it is to make any two distributions have the same mean

Comment: @JamieCarr Let $Y$ have standard normal distribution, $X_n=Y$ for all $n$ and $X=-Y$. The $EX_n=0=EX$ for all $n$ But $E|X_n-X|=2E|X| \neq 0$.